# Memory Corruption on c++ multithreaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, logging

I am developing a multithreaded C++ application, and developed a module for logging. The logging module is a static class, which I call using Logger::Log(string file, string message), that fills a static queue with a `pair<string*,string*>` The queue itself is a `queue<<pair<string*,string*>*>`. Everything is saved as a pointer, as I was trying to avoid garbage collection, and believe pointer variables need specific delete to free the memory.

Now, when one of the threads wants to log something, it calls the Log method, which in turn appends to the end of the queue.

Another thread runs through the queue, pops items and writes them to the designated file.

For some reason, some of the text being written to the file is corrupted, as I am losing part of the begginning or the end of the message.

For example, if I call Log("file", "this is my message"), inside the Log method I am prepending a timestamp, and creating a new string, because I thought the original string might be overwritten, but it still happens.
The problem is that in some situations, what is being written to the file is the timestamp, plus only the end of the message.

This is the full code of the Logger class:

```
#include "Logger.h"

queue<pair<string*, string*>*> Logger::messages;

boost::mutex Logger::loggerLock;

void Logger::CleanOldFiles(vector<string> files){
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it) {
        string filePath = boost::filesystem::current_path().string() + "\\" + *it;
        int result = remove(filePath.c_str());
    }
}

void Logger::Init() {
    Logger::messages = queue<pair<string*, string*>*>();
    boost::thread workerThread(Logger::Process);
    //workerThread.start_thread();
}

void Logger::RawLog(string file, string message) {
    loggerLock.lock();
    string *f = new string(file);
    string *m = new string(message + "\n");
    messages.push(new pair<string*, string*>(f, m));
    loggerLock.unlock();
}

void Logger::Log(string file, string message) {
    loggerLock.lock();
    string *f = new string(file);
    string *m = new string(Functions::CurrentTime() + " (" + boost::lexical_cast<string>(boost::this_thread::get_id()) + "): " + message.c_str() + "\n");
    messages.push(new pair<string*, string*>(f, m));
    loggerLock.unlock();
}


void Logger::Process() {
    while (true) {
        if (Logger::messages.size() == 0) {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200));
            continue;
        }
        loggerLock.lock();
        pair<string*, string*> *entry = messages.front();
        messages.pop();
        loggerLock.unlock();
        ofstream file(boost::filesystem::current_path().string() + "\\" + *(entry->first), ofstream::binary | ofstream::app);
        file.write(entry->second->c_str(), entry->second->length());
        file.close();
        delete entry->first;
        delete entry->second;
        delete entry;
        //cout << entry->second;
    }
}
```

I hope I made myself clear enough...

I do not understand why this is happening, can anyone give me some hints on how to avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need the real code. There's no possible way to find the bug in code we can't see.

Comment: A multithreaded application with no effort of using synchronization?  How did you expect that to work?  A multithreaded app doesn't just mean you start threads.  You must also use synchronization objects such as mutexes, semaphores, etc.   `as I was trying to avoid garbage collection`  C++ is not Java.  What "garbage collection"?

Comment: If on Linux, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for debugging

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what I meant by garbage collection is that for what I could tell, usage of new and pointers in variable requires explicit delete for freeing up memory, whereas variables defined inside a method such as `string s = string("test");` would be released automatically when the scope of the thread changes. Or isn't that the case?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I can put the code of the threads which call the Log method, but I don't see how this can help on understanding the issue. Although, I do think that this issue might be related to resources being freed from the threads which call Log, making the strings messed up. But since I am no C++ expert, and I haven't implemented anything complex in C for more than a few years, I think I am a little lost...I will however post the full code of the Logger class, but I can only do that tomorrow...

Comment: I have added the full code of the class, except for the header file, which I don't think is necessary. Then, there are several threads which call the Log method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for the work I might have caused for all trying to help me, but I corrected the issue. This was actually no memory corruption issue, and my assumption made me search for something where there was no problem.

The issue was on the calling threads, and on the form I was creating the log strings. I was concatenating strings in the wrong way...damn those other programming languages ;)

I was doing something such as Logger::Log("Message: " + integerVariable), which is fact was shifting the string to the right (at least I believe that was what it was doing). When I casted all those variables to strings, everything started working. Thank you for all your help anyway.

Comment: Yes, the expression `"Message: " + integerVariable` is actually a pointer to `char` plus some shift. For example, if your `integerVariable` is equal to one you'll get the `essage: ` string as result. It's inherited from C. In C++ you should use `stringstream` and its operator `<<` to append a number to a string. You mentioned casting - don't do that

Answer (score 2):

The `Logger::Log` *must* be made MT-safe, otherwise you can get two or more threads trying to log something simultaneously. A simplest way to make it MT-safe is a `mutex`.

Comment: I believe the method, as well as the class, is thread safe. I will post the full code tomorrow as I might be forgetting something, but the issue seems to occur from the caller threads, if that is even possible...

Comment: Of course that's possible. Do you have other global variables (besides the `Logger::messages`)?

Comment: I try to define all static global variables as class variables, to avoid unnecessary confusions. Was this what you were thinking about? Even though the issue is resolved, I would like to understand if declaring such variables might be unadvisable.

Answer (score 1):

std::queue is not thread-safe. You need to lock access to all the shared objects or to use thread-safe queue implementation like [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) [provides](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm).

Comment: I know that, and I do use locks. Please take a look at the edited code, as I forgot to place the lock code part.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Logger::messages.size() == 0) {
```

Because `messages` isn't thread safe, you can't call any functions on it when you don't hold the lock. Also, you are still missing `delete` calls for the `string*`s.

You can always just do this:

```
void Logger::Process()
{
    while (true)
    {
        loggerLock.lock();
        if (Logger::messages.size() == 0)
           break;
        loggerLock.unlock();
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200));
    }
    pair<string*, string*> *entry = messages.front();
    messages.pop();
    loggerLock.unlock();
    ofstream file(boost::filesystem::current_path().string() + "\\" +
        *(entry->first), ofstream::binary | ofstream::app);
    file.write(entry->second->c_str(), entry->second->length());
    delete entry->first;
    delete entry->second;
    file.close();
}
```

However, for future reference:

1) Don't use pointers this way. Just use a queue of pairs of strings. The pointers don't buy you anything.

2) Use some sane synchronization mechanism like a condition variable. Don't use `sleep` for synchronization.

3) Use scoped locks and RAII so you don't forget an unlock.

Comment: It was pseudo-code and I missed what I inserted. I am actually inserting a string*. Regarding the delete, I actually removed it when I saw that the strings were getting corrupted, but it was on the code, after the insertion in the file. Please see the updated full code.

Comment: Shouldn't I delete the entry pointer too? I am a little rusty on memory management...Please check the code, I have already put back the deletes. Can you tell me what RAII is? I didn't even know C++ had scoped locks... :)

Comment: Yeah, you need to delete the entry pointer too. Boy, what a mess. Why not just `queue<pair<string, string>> Logger::messages;` and then no `new` or `delete` needed at all. Scoped locks are an example of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) -- basically an object that takes a lock in its constructor and releases it in its destructor.

Comment: Yes it is quite a mess, but since I was unsure if the issue was related to the strings being freed when the scope of the threads changed, I changed every string to a string* that would need explicit delete, just to make sure if that was the issue. Now that I know it isn't I can change it back to its original state... I have more C experience than C++, so I still don't know a lot about the memory management features of C++, so thank you for the tip.

Comment: @user3884729 Here's another tip -- before you ask a question about some code, remove anything you did (other than cleanups or definite improvements) to try to fix the problem. Most likely, they will just wind up obscuring the real issue.

Comment: noted :) just as a clarification, will pointer variables such as string* instead of string and pair<>* instead of pair<> make method calls faster and overall code more performing, as only the addresses are being passed around methods? Honestly, even though avoiding '*', new and delete might be easier on the eyes, I did assume that performance wise, this was the way to go.

Comment: @user3884729 They could, but I doubt that difference would even be noticeable in code like this. You're not passing anything to methods anyway.